# Axios, UseEffect, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

Why is this useEffect goes in inifinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi() {
        let res = await Axios.get(props.url + '/articles')
        props.loadArticles(res.data)
    }

    fetchApi()
})
```

knowing that the component is connected to redux all the way down

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    url: state.ApiReducer.url,
    articles: state.ApiStocksReducer.articles
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadArticles: (data) => dispatch(loadArticles(data)),
    updateSelectedArticle: (data) => dispatch(updateSelectedArticle(data)),
    updateGeneralArticle: (data) => dispatch(updateGeneralArticle(data))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Articles);
```

Comment: Likely because `props.loadArticles(res.data)` updates redux state which gets mapped to props and causes the component to rerender and run the effect again (rinse & repeat) because the effect has no dependency array. When do you *actually* want the effect to run and fetch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conditionally firing an effect The default behavior for effects is to
>   fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is
>   always recreated if one of its dependencies changes.
>
> However, this may be overkill in some cases. We don’t need to create a new
>   subscription on every update, only if the source prop has changed.
>
> To implement this, pass a second argument to useEffect that is the
>   array of values that the effect depends on.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi() {
        let res = await Axios.get(props.url + '/articles')
        props.loadArticles(res.data)
    }

    fetchApi()
}, []);
```